# Missing Settings icons in /System/Library/PreferencePanes/

Tags: macos, monterey, settings, icon, ventura

I guess it might be a bug in Ventura affecting systems that upgraded from Monterey without a clean install. This is how the folder looks to me:
[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think it is broken. I went hunting through my system and found icons that are identical to what you see. As long as the preferences *work* why does it matter that the file icon for each individual preference pane be something custom? And what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't have Ventura to check against… nor have I ever needed to be in that folder ever before, but… They normally have a mini version of the main icon inside the cog, rather than just identical cogs - but as Steve says, what practical problem are you trying to solve? Do they appear correctly in the prefs/settings panel?

Comment: @SteveChambers Those panes can be launched from Alfred and I would like to see the actual icons in Alfred's search results. I heard from the Alfred Team this is a bug in Ventura so I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: @Tetsujin Here's the answer